# Conditionally serialize object members

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

To serialize object to json we do as given below -

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(question);
```

then it returns given json data :-

```
{"que_desc":"devQuestion","qtype":3,"number_of_answer":3,"answers":[{"answer":"answer1","Question":null},{"answer":"answer2","Question":null},{"answer":"answer3","Question":null}]}
```

but I want to ignore "Question" property and need data as given below-

```
{
"que_desc": "This is Question details",
"qtype" : "1",
"number_of_answer" : "3",
"answers": [{"answer": "A", "is_default": "true"}, {"answer": "B"}, {"answer": "C"}]}
```

I want to ignore "Question" property while converting into json.
so how we will conditionally serialize object members at run time??

Comment: You can create an anonymous object that does not include the property and then serialize that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Json.NET` nuget and the `[JsonIgnore]` atribute at the `que_desc` property.

If you need more functionality, you can implemente de serialize methods by your self using Json.NET.

[More Info](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size)

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate the `Question` property with the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute.

For further info, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Supposing that `Answer` has a definition like the below:

```
public class Answer
{
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public Question Question { get; set; }

    // rest
}
```

If you change it to the following:

```
public class Answer
{
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public Question Question { get; set; }

    // rest 
}
```

You will get that you want.